# Setting a variable stored inside an iframe from the parent page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hello I am building a site where an iframe is the majority of one page. I would like to know if it is possible to use code on the page in which the iframe is located to change a javascript variable that lives inside the iframe's source.

Example: www.foobar.com/iframe-source.html

```
<body>
    <script>
        var a = 'Hello';
    </script>
</body>
```

Page source:

```
<body>
    <iframe src="www.foobar.com/iframe-source.html/">
</body>
```

In this example i would want to change the var "a" to Goodbye instead of Hello

Comment: Yes, **if** your situation meets the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). See my brief [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35918701/2813224) as well. In your generic example what you need is that the parent page belongs to `http://www.foobar.com` as well.

Comment: So if the iframe is pulling a page from a domain outside of it's own then I have no way to set any variables?

Comment: There is a way but it's not simple and you need editing privileges for both pages.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I don't have editing permissions on the iframes site so that's kinda out of the question. Thanks for the clarification though!